# Authentication multiple Backend Apis

Tags: authentication, nestjs

I'm having the following scenario:

- A frontend SPA based on Vue.
- A Nest.js-Application providing an API
- The user should authenticate against the Nest.js Application with Azure AD.
  The Nest.js Application should provides several Endpoints where other Apis (e.g LinkedIn or Graph) should be consumed.

My Question now is if this scenario is realizable and if yes how do I have to implement the Authentication for the External Apis which are consumed by the Nest-Application?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want users to be able to authenticate with Azure AD, LinkedIn e.t.c. for LinkedIn you can use http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-linkedin-oauth2/, the goal is to get a token that contains the user's information after authorization with these external APIs on the backend, you have to set a URL on the backend that points to the frontend with the token appended, on the frontend, you need to provide the callback URL, get the token from the URL, then you do a redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your quick respose. Maybe I should specify it more: The Vue-Application should fetch data from different backend apis, emails from Graph or Contacts from Linkedin for example. These data are user dependent, so the User has to authenticate for every backend Api. The Login in the Vue-Application should be done via AzureAD (https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad). The question now is, how the user should authenticate for the multiple backend apis for fetching user dependent data from them.